# SFP with copper NIC

Tags: communication, ethernet

We are designing a gigabit copper NIC card. Can we use SFP connectors with copper, or SFP is used only with fiber?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SFP is not a type of connector in that sense, it is a form factor for transceiver modules.  SFP modules plug into something (e.g. a switch or router) to provide the connectivity required.

Copper SFP modules do exist, for example here is an SFP module that connects to a copper network:

[image: SFP module with copper]
<sub>(source: [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:10GBase-T_SFP%2B_Transceiver.jpg))</sub>

So you could design your gigabit network card to support SFP modules, that way the end user could plug in the transceiver for whatever network they desire.  Cards like this are already available, for example the one below has two slots for SFP modules:

[image: SFP network card]
<sub>(source: [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Qlogic_qle2672-ck.jpg))</sub>